# Ubuntu Server 12.04 hardware support

Tags: 12.04, server, hardware, compatibility

What is the hardware support like for Ubuntu on servers? Can I install Ubuntu 12.04 on any server and expect everything to work?

In particular, I'm looking at SuperMicro servers (model: SM 6027R-72RFT+) and a Huawei Server (mode: TECAL RH 2285 V2)

I'm aware of the certified hardware list on Ubuntu site, however it is restricted to HP/DELL/Lenovo brands, and is a very limited list. Should I follow that list when choosing a Ubuntu Server (ver: 12.04) or do I have a more free choice?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Hardware-HOWTO/).

Comment: What's the intended usage? I see you're looking at what are essentially Data Center class servers.

Comment: @Mitch thats a really old link, and for example under 'SCSI RAID Controllers' one device is listed.

Comment: @douggro these are enterprise class servers. I dont know the exact usage, however it is going to the admissions department of a university.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the nature of the hardware, it's a pretty safe bet that Ubuntu Server would work just fine on them. The Huawei model didn't have any detailed specs that I could find; the SuperMicro model did have a "supported OS's" list that included Red Hat Enterprise Linux. Typically, Enterprise-class hardware is well-supported with most Linux-based distros.